# Issue with contour plot

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot a variable z that's computed using variables x and y. I tried a few different plotting options, but all graphs come up empty, and I don't know what's happening.

I tried playing with different lengths for the 'jaccard' vector, but it doesn't seem to be a size problem. I also checked a lot of other posts and I don't see what could be causing the issue.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly) 
library(lattice)

pt1 <- expand.grid(nodes = seq(2, 455, by = 1), jaccard = seq(0.1, 100, by = 0.1)) %>%
  mutate(dense = "not")
pt2 <- expand.grid(nodes = seq(2, 455, by = 1), jaccard = seq(0.1, 100, by = 0.1)) %>%
  mutate(dense = "fully")
data <- rbind(pt1, pt2) %>%
  mutate(sumJ = case_when(
    dense == "not" ~ (nodes-1)*jaccard,
    dense == "fully" ~ (nodes*(nodes-1)/2)*jaccard,
    TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  mutate(WD = 2 * sumJ / (nodes * (nodes - 1))) %>%
  select(nodes, sumJ, WD) %>%
  distinct()

plot_ly(z = ~data$WD, type = "contour")

contourplot(WD ~ nodes + sumJ, data=data)
```

Comment: Doesn't `z` need to be a matrix? https://plotly.com/r/contour-plots/

Comment: The docs say it must be *"dataframe column, list, vector"* (ref: https://plotly.com/r/reference/contour/#contour-z), though I find that inconsistent with the first paragraph on that page, *"Data in `z` must be a 2D list of numbers"*. This documentation shows plotly's preference for python (not R), since while R treats "lists" and "vectors/arrays" very differently, most other programming languages do not. @Friede

Comment: ... but I do think @Friede is right: I just tried the first example in https://plotly.com/r/contour-plots/, replacing `z`'s matrix with a direct `data.frame` version of it, and the plot had no elements. Further, don't you need to give the `x=` and `y=` arguments to `plot_ly`?

Comment: Does your use of `contourplot` do anything on your side? For me, it spun (busily) for several minutes and then presented a very-anti-climactic https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzc50.png. It would be very useful I think if your comparison had a working example on at least one side.

Comment: @r2evans, interesting investigation. Thank you. I agree on *It would be very useful I think if your comparison had a working example on at least one side.*

Comment: Djoustaine, I'm sorry, I re-read and understand ... you don't care if it's plotly or lattice (or perhaps ggplot2?), you want a contour plot, and both of these methods fail. Okay, sorry about that noise. I recognize you're trying to produce a reproducible question here, and I applaud that effort. However, it's not clear to me what the "x" and "y" variables on the plot should be ... `nodes` might be one, but is `sumJ` your "y"?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Indeed, I don't care about the package used to produce the graph. x and y can be inverted, but originally the sumJ was going to be y. 

In the meantime, I think I found why there are problems with the graph: the values of y (sumJ) are unique.